# Variable number of fields to output in Select-Object cmdlet

Tags: powershell, output, select-object

Let's say that I have an Obj with data describing multiple entities.
I want to output it like this (CSV, HTML, Format-Table, whatever):

```
Property Code   Property descr.  Entity1  Entity2  Entity3
abs_de234       abs prop for de  132      412      412
abs_fe234       abs prop for fe  423      432      234
...             ...              ...      ...      ...
```

I would use something like:

```
$ObjData | % {Select-Object @{Label = "Property Code"; Expression = {$_.propcode}}, @{Label = "Property Desc."; Expression = {$_.descr}},  @{Label = "Entity1"; Expression = {$_.entity1}}, @{Label = "Entity2"; Expression = {$_.entity2}},@{Label = "Entity3"; Expression = {$_.entity3}} }| Format-Table
```

But what if my object has variable number of entities? Let's say these properties are all in an array:

```
$EntityList = @('Entity1', 'Entity2', 'Entity4', 'Entity5', 'Entity5')
```

How, based on `$EntityList` I can construct corresponding `Select-Object` command?

Upd.: Based on Help for `Select-Object`:

```
Select-Object
  [-InputObject <PSObject>]
  [[-Property] <Object[]>]
  [-ExcludeProperty <String[]>]
  [-ExpandProperty <String>]
  [-Unique]
  [-Last <Int32>]
  [-First <Int32>]
  [-Skip <Int32>]
  [-Wait]
  [<CommonParameters>]
```

Does this mean I should be able to just use `Select-Object -Property $EntityList`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `| % {Select-Object`

Don't use `%` (the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet) to pipe to `Select-Object` - pipe *directly* to `Select-Object`.

> `@{Label = "Entity1"; Expression = {$_.entity1}}`

Unless you need to change the *case* of the label (property) name, just pass `entity1` to `Select-Object`.

As with any cmdlet parameter that accepts an *array* of objects, you're free to pass the array either as an array literal (with the elements enumerated one by one with `,`) or as a previously constructed array passed via a variable:

```
# Properties that need renaming.
# Note: Unless you need to *transform* the input property value,
#       you don't strictly need a *script block* ({ ... }) and can use
#       a *string* with the property name instead.
#       E.g., instead of {$_.propcode} you can use 'propcode'
$propDefs = 
  @{Label = "Property Code"; Expression = {$_.propcode}}, 
  @{Label = "Property Desc."; Expression = {$_.descr}}

# Add properties that can be extracted as-is:
$propDefs += 'Entity1', 'Entity2', 'Entity4', 'Entity5', 'Entity5'

# Note: Passing the array *positionally* implies binding to the -Property parameter.
$ObjData | Select-Object $propDefs # add Format-Table, if needed, for display formatting
```

---

To demonstrate:

```
# Sample input object
$ObjData = [pscustomobject] @{
  propcode = 'pc'
  descr = 'descr'
  Entity1 = 'e1'
  Entity2 = 'e2'
  Entity3 = 'e3'
  Entity4 = 'e4'
  Entity5 = 'e5'
}

$propDefs = 
  @{Label = "Property Code"; Expression = {$_.propcode}}, 
  @{Label = "Property Desc."; Expression = {$_.descr}}

$propDefs += 'Entity1', 'Entity2', 'Entity3', 'Entity4', 'Entity5'

$ObjData | Select-Object $propDefs
```

The above yields:

```
Property Code  : pc
Property Desc. : descr
Entity1        : e1
Entity2        : e2
Entity3        : e3
Entity4        : e4
Entity5        : e5
```

Comment: Ok, yes, it works in this case. What might be wrong when I have a CSV file that looks like my original table, export it using `$ObjData = Import-CSV -Path $path` and try to do the same?

Comment: @miguello That's impossible to tell without further information - did you not get helpful answers to your related question?

Comment: Well, it's been helpful and I confirmed that it works the way you wrote it. And as you have said my problem might lie somewhere else. Looks like the Object that I construct during my script is not of the same structure as just a CSV read from file. I kept experimenting with it and the only way it would output the same way is if I spell the properties line verbatim, like `@{Label = "..."; Expression = {...}}`. When calling `GetType()` method on both objects - mine and one read directly from CSV, it shows Array of Objects on both. This will be my next step: find differences between structures

Comment: @miguello pipe the variables to `Get-Member` instead, which will tell you the actual type of the array's _elements_ - PowerShell arrays are `[object[]]`-typed, which means they can contains objects of any type.